# a class derived from a class compliant with Decodable protocol yields a compiler error 'Class 'CardListResponse' has no initializers'

Tags: decodable, swift5

```
public struct CodeAndDetails: Codable {
    public let html: String
    public var code: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case html = "DETAILS", code = "CODE"
    }

    public func getMessage(font: UIFont) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let res = NSAttributedString(html: html, font: font)
        return res
    }
}

public class BaseResponse: Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case successDetails = "Success"
    }
    public let successDetails: [CodeAndDetails]
}
```

**here:**

```
public class CardListResponse: BaseResponse {
    public let cards: [DebitCard]?
    public let activeCardId: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cards = "row"
        case activeCardId = "CurrentActiveId"
    }
}
```

I get:

> Class 'CardListResponse' has no initializers

What are my options to deal with this swift bogosity?

The problem moved into runtime. The sister question is here:
[Swift Decodable fails for a class derived from a decodable compliant class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146148/swift-decodable-fails-for-a-class-derived-from-a-decodable-compliant-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `CardListResponse` properties to `var` not to `let`

- `let` is constant which means you can not change value

**What can you do?**

- You can set default value to `cards` and `activeCardId` properties like:

  ```
  public class CardListResponse: BaseResponse {
      public let cards: [DebitCard]? = nil
      public let activeCardId: Int? = nil

      enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
          case cards = "row"
          case activeCardId = "CurrentActiveId"
      }
  }
  ```

*OR*

- You can change `let` to `var` like:

  ```
  public class CardListResponse: BaseResponse {
      public var cards: [DebitCard]?
      public var activeCardId: Int?

      enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
          case cards = "row"
          case activeCardId = "CurrentActiveId"
      }
  }
  ```

I hope it is works.

Enjoy.

Comment: I forgot to mention that nil approach keeping them let did not work.

Comment: Hi @AntonTropashko, is the error the same `Class 'CardListResponse' has no initializers` ?

Comment: successDetails in the base class parses just fine though, it's the vars in derived class that stay nil

Comment: no, changing to var fixed it. But Decodable is bork. I suppose, technically, you have resolved the compile time issue and run time screwage is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Please share more code for example your response `JSON` and `DebitCard` model. I will check your 'sister' question :) Enjoy

Comment: See sister question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146148/swift-decodable-fails-for-a-class-derived-from-a-decodable-compliant-class