# Swift Decodable fails for a class derived from a decodable compliant class (JSONDecoder is used for decoding)

Tags: json, swift, runtime

```
public struct CodeAndDetails: Codable {
    public let html: String
    public var code: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case html = "DETAILS", code = "CODE"
    }

    public func getMessage(font: UIFont) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let res = NSAttributedString(html: html, font: font)
        return res
    }
}

public class BaseResponse: Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case successDetails = "Success"
    }
    public let successDetails: [CodeAndDetails]
}
```

**here:**

```
public class CardListResponse: BaseResponse {
    public var cards: [DebitCard]?
    public var activeCardId: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cards = "row"
        case activeCardId = "CurrentActiveId"
    }
}
```

Does not decode properly. cards and activeCardId stay nil. When I change public class CardListResponse: BaseResponse to public class CardListResponse: Decodable the cards and activeCardId parse just fine (but obviously I get no payload from base class).

How could I cope with this?

In case it's not clear from the question here's sample json:

**My JSON**

```
{  
   "row":[  
      {  
         "PicPath":"MC"
      },
      {  
         "IsDefault":"",
         "PicPath":"VISA"
      }
   ],
   "CurrentActiveId":17504322,
   "Success":[  
      {  
         "DETAILS":"\u0412\u044b\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u043d\u043e \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e",
         "CODE":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

```
public struct DebitCard: Decodable
{
    public let accountContractId: Int?
    public let last8: String?
    public let balanceString: String?

    public let currName: String?
    public let iCardId: Int?
    public let isMain: Bool?
    public let cardNameWithCurrencyCode: String?
    public let card4: String?

    public let title: String?
    public let picPath: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case accountContractId = "AcntContractId"
        case expire = "Expire"
        case last8 = "Card8"
        case balanceString = "Balance"

        case currName = "CurrName"
        case iCardId
        case isMainString = "isMain"
        case cardNameWithCurrencyCode = "CardName"

        case card4 = "Card4"
        case title = "CrdTInfo" 
        case picPath = "PicPath"

    }
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        accountContractId = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .accountContractId)
        last8 = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .last8)
        balanceString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .balanceString)
        currName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .currName)
        iCardId = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .iCardId)
        let isMainString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .isMainString)
        isMain = isMainString.toBool
        cardNameWithCurrencyCode = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .cardNameWithCurrencyCode)
        card4 = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .card4)
        title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        picPath = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .picPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your response with `JSON`  and `DebitCard` model.

Comment: Added. Though it's pretty much irrelevant cause CardListResponse works fine when you change BaseResponse to Decodable. As soon as it becomes root class with no superclass parsing works. As soon as you derive from BaseResponse cards and activeCardId don't get decoded and stay nil.

Comment: How do you use these classes in your request?

Comment: It's fed by the networking layer to JSONDecoder()

Comment: Please try to use `BaseResponse` to decode cards and activeCardId properties. I mean you don't want two different models for this response. You can use one model for this response. If I can't tell you exactly, I can write as an answer.

Comment: "Success" is present in a boatload of different response types. I don't want to duplicate the boilerplate from the BaseResponse all over the place. If I did I could've just as well went with structs.

Comment: Can you share `DebitCard` model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196852/discussion-between-anton-tropashko-and-emre-ciftci).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)` in the subclass and call the superclass init although you don't need to implement it for the superclass

init for `CardListResponse`, notice the call to super.init

```
required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    cards = try container.decode([DebitCard].self, forKey: .cards)
    activeCardId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .activeCardId)
    try super.init(from: decoder)
}
```

---

Another option is to skip inheritance altogether and use composition instead. In the subclass you make a property for the `CodeAndDetails` array instead, this way you won't need a special `init` method anymore.

CardListResponse can then be changed to below and the super class can be removed. In the long run I think this is a more attractive solution.

```
public class CardListResponse: Decodable {
    public var cards: [DebitCard]?
    public var activeCardId: Int?
    public var details: [CodeAndDetails]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cards = "row"
        case activeCardId = "CurrentActiveId"
        case details = "Success"
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, what a hassle. This idiocy is due to swift runtime or JSONDecodable??

Comment: getting Ambiguous reference to member 'CodingKeys'

Comment: @AntonTropashko Declare them private

Comment: I can't believe I'd have to add init for every single decodable derived from that. I'll probably end up duplicating success from the base all over the place. Enums can't be derived from a base enum, right?

Comment: @AntonTropashko I have added an alternative solution if you mustn't use inheritance